# OpenGL directly to Linux framebuffer without X-Server

Tags: linux, opengl, framebuffer, mesa, directfb

I have a small OpenGL application that has been developed using GLUT. What are my best options to render directly to a Linux framebuffer (fbdev) with OpenGL, without an X-Server? I understand that GLUT needs X, so I'm not looking for ways to use GLUT without X.

The framebuffer device I intend to use is confirmed working with `fbi` and `mplayer`.

I have done (or I'd like to think that I have done) a pretty exhaustive research, and found some resources and libraries that might work. But most of the info is a bit outdated, and I'm not sure what to trust.

- DirectFB looks good, exactly what I'm looking for, but does not seem to be in active development.

  - I'm inclined to try this out on my target device: https://github.com/mcdoh/glGears-on-DirectFB-with-OpenGL-ES - but again, this is the only example code I can find, and it's six years old.
- Mesa is another interesting candidate, but I can't seem to find any recent information.

  - This looks interesting: http://www.mesa3d.org/glfbdev-driver.html - but I can not find any example code to go from.

So, while a lot of SO answers mention DirectFB and Mesa as solutions, I can't bring myself to be confident in those options while so little material can be found.

So, if you can point me in the right direction here, give me any examples to go from, that would be highly appreciated. What am I missing?

---

Edit due to question being marked as duplicate:

The answer to the related question recommends using DRM. I intend to run my code on an Allwinner H3-based embedded computer that does not yet support the mainline Linux kernel. Currently, it's running on kernel version 3.14, which I believe does not have DRM support.

So, are there any alternatives?

Comment: @datenwolf has an updated [`kmscube`](https://github.com/datenwolf/kmscube)

Comment: See updated question

Comment: @dingari you [might have the mainline](https://linux-sunxi.org/H3#Sunxi_Community) now